# Model an information system which communicates with other information systems in a UML-diagram?

Tags: uml, modeling

I have to develop an integration concept to integrate my software as a subsystem into an enterprise information system which communicates with other information systems in other institutions.

I want to show a diagram which explains how the several subsystems are connected and which data is communicated between the subsystems. My problem is that I'm not sure if there is in the UML language a diagram-type that supports modeling of complete information systems.

I thought about the deployment diagram, but I am not sure if it is the right. I don't want to start an then recognize that it is the wrong way.

Is there any advice which diagram should be used,  or if there is an alternative modeling language for complex information systems?

Comment: FYI, *HL7 is a data interchange format for the health care industry, not a communication protocol.&  To design the system in UML it's best to start with a good UML modeling tool. As for your reservations about UML not being "complete enough" I'm pretty sure it is up to the task for the individual  sufficiently fluent in UML. . .

Comment: Isn't HL7 a layer 7 based protocol like http. I think so. But this is not the main thing in my question. For UML design I currently use StarUML and ArgoUML. I know it is not the best, but it is the only what I have currently. It isn't clear to me what diagram of the uml should be used, yet.

Comment: Health Level 7 - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia, en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Level_7

Comment: I know this wiki-entry. hl7.org says that HL7 is a "Application Protocol for Electronic Data Exchange in Healthcare Environments", look here hl7.org/implement/standards/index.cfm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A **component diagram** is what you want - see chapter 25 of "The Unified Modeling Language User Guide".

Answer (score -1):

> I want to show a diagram which explains how the several subsystems work together and which data is communicated between the subsystems.

I'd probably start with a conceptual [sequence diagram](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html).

So, for example, you could have your **lifelines** represent the various components that you're integrating with, and your **interactions** could be any of the messages that need to transfer to and from those components.

Comment: sequence diagram is a diagram to show a process. What i want is to show a structural model of an complete information system with all its sub-systems, for example a patient-administration-software and a laboratory-information-and-management-system that are communication via hl7. I want to have shown the interfaces and subsytems